# Chess pieces metrics in higher dimensions

Tags: graph-theory, metric-spaces, integer-sequences, chess, graph-distance

A couple of days ago, I was thinking about applying the knight (the well-known piece of chess) metric to any cubic lattice $\mathbb{N}^k$, $k \in \mathbb{N}-\{0,1\}$.
I suddenly realized that, from $k = 3$ and beyond, it would be hard to provide sequences similar to **A232007** from the OEIS (e.g., if $k = 3$, we would have $a(n) = 0, -1, -1, h(4), \dots$, where $h(4) \in \{3,4\}$). Maybe this has already been achieved by someone else, so I would like to read more about it (in recent years I have written something related to the unsolvable KTP inside a $ 3 \times 3$ board, see the third section of https://ejournal2.undip.ac.id/index.php/jfma/article/view/10106).
Moreover, I have just seen that, on the OEIS, is missing the very basic pawn sequence "Maximal number of moves needed by a pawn to reach every square from a fixed position on an $n \times n$ chessboard, or -1 if it is not possible to reach every square (a pawn can move by one or two squares forward by performing its first move)", which would be as follows: $a(n) = 0, 2, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, \dots$, since $a(n) = n, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}-\{0, 1, 3\}$. I am planning to submit it when my holding/pending sequences will be processed.

Finally, I am considering also to apply (to any given $k$-dimensional cubic lattice) different chess pieces metrics (with the only exception of the bishop, even if we could define by default the distance between any pair of squares of different colors as $2^k$ or so in order to letting the triangular inequality still holds), such as the rook or the queen so that their generalized metric would turn into an interesting excercise in higher dimensions, if $n$ is sufficiently large.

Has anyone already answered this type of question, by any chance?

Comment: It seems to me the answer for the diameter for the rook's graph in higher dimensions would be k for n>1. We can only change one of a rook's coordinates at a time per move, making k the answer.

Comment: Yes, absolutely... the same diameter would also hold for the queen's graph, $\forall k>2$ (i.e., it is equal to $1$ if $k \leq 2$).
Thus, the diameter for the pawn's graph should be always $\leq k + n - 1$.

Comment: I think the k dimensional queens graph has diameter less than k, for n>1.  Imagine we have n=2.  If we differ in k coordinates between our pair of squares then our distance is less than k - since we can change two coordinates at a time by moving diagonally.

Comment: Of course, Paul... in the comment above I meant $n > 2$ instead of $k$, my bad. My point is that (considering the queen's graph) if $n := 2$, then a unitary diameter holds for any $k \in \mathbb{N}-\{0,1\}$.

Comment: I think you're still missing things.  If I'm not mistaken the diameter for the                       
  $3 \times 3 \times 3$ queen's graph is $2$.  This is in contradiction, as $k=3$ for this case.

Comment: About the queen's graph $3 \times 3 \times 3$. Just tried with a pen and a squared sheet, checking all the four cases, I confirm that the diameter is unitary iff we start from the central cell of the cube and it is equal to $2$ if not, so $2$ definitely holds. In the meantime, I have also proved that the diameter of the knight's graph is $4$ for the $3 \times 3 \times 3$ set, while (in $\mathbb{R}^k$) it should necessary hold the following (trivial) bound: $\lceil \frac{n \cdot \sqrt{k}}{\sqrt{5}} \rceil \leq {d_n}^{k}(K) \leq 3 \cdot k \cdot (n-1)$.

Comment: In the above mentioned generalized bound for the knight's graph, I am assuming that $n \geq 4$ and $k \geq 2$, for obvious reasons.

Comment: @PaulBurchett, there are at least two ways to generalise the rook's movement. One is, as you say, to change only one coordinate, and that is also my intuition about the natural way to generalise to higher dimensions, but an alternative is to change between one and (dimension minus one) coordinates. I have seen this definition used in a paper I read about a year ago; I think it was related to a project I was working on about Comtet numbers, but I can't find it in my bibliographic notes for that project.

Comment: I had never heard of that way to generalize for the rook's graph for higher dimensions.  For the case where the rook's movement is generalized by changing between one and $d-1$ coordinates the diameter will always be 2 (for $n>1$).  The diameter for that case is easy to show.

@Peter Taylor - Is there more than one generalization for the queen as well?  I'd assume so.  We should make sure we're talking about the same generalization.  I'm talking about the generalization where the queen can change any one dimension by any number, or change two of its dimensions equally.

Comment: @PaulBurchett, the obvious extension of the alternative generalisation for the rook to the queen is that she can change any (non-zero) number of dimensions by the same (non-zero) number. This hyperqueen would be weaker than the hyperrook in 3 or more dimensions.

Comment: Very interesting, thank you! Anyway, here is a related OEIS sequence, containing the proof (in its comment section) of the 3D solution for the knight (i.e, a(n) = n for n >= 4): A359740.